# Implementing LSResourceResolver for reading set of XSD recursively

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I need to load XSD files from jar, so implemented LSResourceResolver as follows:

```
        Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/xsd/root/maindoc/MainSchema.xsd"));
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(new LSResourceResolver(){
            @Override
            public LSInput resolveResource(String type, String namespaceURI, String publicId, String systemId, String baseURI) {
                    LSInput input = new DOMInputImpl();
                String filePath = getNormalizedPath("resources/xsd/root/maindoc/", systemId);
                InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
                input.setPublicId(publicId);
                input.setSystemId(systemId);
                input.setBaseURI(baseURI);
                input.setCharacterStream(new InputStreamReader(stream));             
                return input;
            }

        });         
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
```

Such implementation successfully resolves links from the main schema, but fails to resolve links from referenced documents.

With a call from referenced document I receive not null baseURI parameter, but it's value is like "file:///var/xxx/yyy.xsd" in my case, so it does not look possible to construct a valid path from this and systemId.

Am I missing something? Should it be possible to make resolver work recursively?

Surely there is a workaround with flattening the schema, but I don't like it much.

Answer (score 11):

Consider using method `newSchema(URL schema)`.

I've just had a similar problem and implementing `LSResourceResolver` seems like too much trouble. Just take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342859/3227133). I have no idea if it handles recursive includes, but it definitely looks too complicated for such a simple task.

I've found [this article](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/10/xml_processing.html). It's quite old but the general idea is still valid: it's often better to use `URL` than `InputStream` for schema reading.

Advantages of using `URL` interface:

- Simple construction from files and resources without custom `LSResourceResolver`
- Buffering is handled by implementation.

You can't (gracefully) use this interface to read schema from a real stream (standard input or network connection). It is obviously supposed to be done with the stream interfaces. But I guess that most applications actually read schema from the host file system or application resources.

Example:

```java
java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("resources/main.xsd");
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(
    XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
schemaFactory.setErrorHandler(new CustomErrorHandler());
try {
    schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(url);
} catch (SAXException e) {
    //...
}
```

Note the custom error handler. For some reason Xerces emits just a warning for a missing include file. To make it throw an exception implement a handler like this:

```java
class CustomErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

    public void fatalError(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        throw e;
    }

    public void error(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        throw e;
    }

    public void warning(SAXParseException e) throws SAXException {
        throw e;
    }

}
```

Comment: The URL approach proved to be simple, elegant and effective. Thanks!

Comment: This saved me so much time.  This should be the accepted answer.