# XML String Validation with two XSD Strings (with include) / how does LSResourceResolver work?

Tags: java, string, xsd, include

I am trying to validate an XML String against two Strings that contains an XSD. One XSD includes the other. I get the error:
"Cannot resolve the name 'ServiceSpecificationSchema:ServiceIdentifier' to a(n) 'type definition' component."

It looks like, that my code doesnt recognize the second XSD file. Others solved that problem by using a LSResourceResolver ( seen here: [How to validate an XML file using Java with an XSD having an include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342808/how-to-validate-an-xml-file-using-java-with-an-xsd-having-an-include/2342859#2342859) )

But in that exampe the files are stored local. Is there a good way, that this method works with my XSD strings?

Any hint would be appreciated.

My code so far:

> ```
>         SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
>
>         Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new SAXSource[]
>                 {
>                         (new SAXSource(new InputSource(new StringReader(XSD)))),
>                         (new SAXSource(new InputSource(new StringReader(XSD2))))
>                 });
>         Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
>
>         validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(inputXml)));
> ```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i found a solution.

This works for me:

```
@Service
public class ResourceResolverImpl implements LSResourceResolver {
private ILoadFromSRService iLoadFromSRService;

@Autowired
public ResourceResolverImpl(ILoadFromSRService iLoadFromSRService){
    this.iLoadFromSRService = iLoadFromSRService;
}

public LSInput resolveResource(String type,
                               String namespaceURI,
                               String publicId,
                               String systemId,
                               String baseURI) {
    String string =iLoadFromSRService.getServiceBaseTypeSchema();
    string = string.replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "");
    InputStream resourceAsStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( string.getBytes());
    return new LSInputImpl(publicId, systemId, resourceAsStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share the example completed?