# XML validation - element not declared

Tags: java, xsd, xml-validation

I don't get this xml:

```
<mappings>
 <mapping>
  <protobufMessage>pb::Header</protobufMessage>
  <rosPackage>std_msgs</rosPackage>
  <rosMessage>Header</rosMessage>
 </mapping>
</mappings>
```

validated against this schema, which is defined inline in the source code:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified"
>
<xs:element name="mappings">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="mapping" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="protobufMessage" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="rosPackage" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="rosMessage" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

I get the error message

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration
>   of element 'mappings'.    at [...]

The code for validation (xtend code):

```
def private validate(InputStream is) {
    val parserF = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance
    val parser = parserF.newDocumentBuilder 
    val document = parser.parse(is)
    val validatorF = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
    val schemaSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(schema)) // schema is a String member which contains the schema
    val valSchema = validatorF.newSchema(schemaSource)
    val validator = valSchema.newValidator
    validator.validate(new DOMSource(document))
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a header in your xml? You should add a `xs:schema ... targetNamespace="myns"` to the `xsd` and have `<xml xmlns="myns" ... >` in the xml.

Comment: @daniu: Not exactly.   OP's XML is not using namespaces.  See [**duplicate link**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35411871/290085) for `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` help.

Comment: @kjhughes I defined the schema inline in the code, is `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` still applicable?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that.  Ok, I've add [**duplicate link**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2342808/290085) that shows a `ResourceResolver` example.

Comment: @kjhughes I think I see. What you are saying is that I should use `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` to provide a URL for the schema, and use `LSResourceResolver` to resolve that URL to a Stream on the schema.

Comment: For the record: none of the "duplicates" helped, what did in the end help was setting `namespaceAware = true` on the DocumentBuilderFactory.

Comment: What you say helped is not consistent with the XML you've posted.  That XML is not in a namespace.

Comment: @kjhughes Well what do I know why it helped. I can only say that the shown code and schema + xml is exactly what I am using.