# XML Schema with multiple includes; validate in java

Tags: java, xml

Suppose I have an XML schema `.xsd` file which has many such `<xsd:include schemaLocation="../Common/{dir}" />` elements among other types of `xsd:include` statements. I am trying to validate an input file in java:

```
public static void validate(String xml_file, String schema_file, String base_dir) throws 
 SAXException, IOException {
     SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
     InputStream input_stream = new FileInputStream(schema_file);
     ((sf.newSchema(new StreamSource(input_stream, base_dir))).newValidator()).validate(new StreamSource(new File(xml_file)));
 }
```

However, I am getting a `Cannot find the declaration of element '[element_type]'`, when that `[element_type]` is clearly referred to in the `schema_file` include statements. Is there something I am doing wrong? How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: My suspicions would fall on the value of `base_dir`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an XML file using Java with an XSD having an include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342808/how-to-validate-an-xml-file-using-java-with-an-xsd-having-an-include)

Comment: For `base_dir` I am providing the path to the deepest folder containing my `schema_file`. I am not sure what value to pass.